# Alterar email de resposta php mailer

Tags: php

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
    if(isset($_POST['sendContato'])){
        $nome = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'nome'));            
        $telefone = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'telefone'));
        $email = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email'));
        $mensagem = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'mensagem'));

        if(($nome == '') OR ($telefone == '') OR ($email == '') OR ($mensagem == '')){
            echo "<div class='false'>Por Favor, Preencha os Campos em branco!</div>";
        }elseif(!validaEmail($email)) {
            echo "<div class='false'>O e-mail inserido é invalido!</div>";
        }else{
            $date = date("d/m/Y");
            $horass = date('H:i:s');
            $nome_usermail="Nome do Site";
            $login_usermail="admin@nomedosite.com.br";
            $senha_usermail="SENHA DO EMAIL";
            $subject_usermail="Contato do Site";    

            $to_reposta="admin@nomedosite.com.br";   
            $to_mail[1]= $dEmailDestino['email'];
            $to_nome[1]="Administrador";  
            //$to_nome[2]="Nome..."; 

            require_once('dts/mail/class.phpmailer.php');

            $mail = new PHPMailer(); // INICIA A CLASSE PHPMAILER 
            $mail->IsSMTP(); //ESSA OPÇÃO HABILITA O ENVIO DE SMTP
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
            $mail->Port = 587; // Indica a porta de conexão para a saída de e-mails

            $mail->Host = 'smtp.'.substr(strstr($login_usermail, '@'), 1); //SERVIDOR DE SMTP, USE smtp.SeuDominio.com OU smtp.hostsys.com.br
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; //ATIVA O SMTP AUTENTICADO
            $mail->Username = "$login_usermail"; //EMAIL PARA SMTP AUTENTICADO (pode ser qualquer conta de email do seu domínio)
            $mail->Password = "$senha_usermail"; //SENHA DO EMAIL PARA SMTP AUTENTICADO 
            $mail->From = "$to_reposta"; //E-MAIL DO REMETENTE 
            $mail->FromName = "$nome_usermail"; //NOME DO REMETENTE

            for($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++){
                $mail->AddAddress("$to_mail[$i]","$to_nome[$i]"); //E-MAIL DO DESINATÁRIO, NOME DO DESINATÁRIO --> AS VARIÁVEIS ALI PODEM FAZER REFERÊNCIA A DADOS VINDO DE $_GET OU $_POST, OU AINDA DO BANCO DE DADOS
            }

            /*
            for($i=1;$i<=count($to_mail);$i++){
                $mail->AddAddress("$to_mail[2]","$to_nome[$i]"); //E-MAIL DO DESINATÁRIO, NOME DO DESINATÁRIO --> AS VARIÁVEIS ALI PODEM FAZER REFERÊNCIA A DADOS VINDO DE $_GET OU $_POST, OU AINDA DO BANCO DE DADOS
            }
            */

            $mail->WordWrap = 50; // ATIVAR QUEBRA DE LINHA
            $mail->IsHTML(true); //ATIVA MENSAGEM NO FORMATO HTML
            $mail->Subject = "$subject_usermail"; //ASSUNTO DA MENSAGEM 
            $mail->Body = "
            Nome: $nome<br/>
            E-mail: $email<br/>
            Telefone: $telefone<br/>
            Mensagem: $mensagem<br/><br/>

            Data: $date - $horass
            "; //MENSAGEM NO FORMATO HTML, PODE SER TEXTO OU IMAGEM 

            // verifica se está tudo ok com oa parametros acima, se nao, avisa do erro. Se sim, envia. 

            if(!$mail->Send()){
                echo "<script>
                       alert('Os dados não podem ser enviados! Erro.: $mail->ErrorInfo'); 
                       location.href='".BASE."/contato'; 
                       </script>";
                //echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                //$status_contato=2;
            }else{  
                echo $_SESSION['return'] = '<div class="posiTivo">E-mail enviado com sucesso!</div>';                   
                header('Location: '.BASE.'/contato');
                //$status_contato=1;                    
            }


        }
    }
```

O problema é que o e-mail: admin@nomedosite.com.br é apenas para configurar o usuário e senha do php mailer!

Eu queria colocar um outro e-mail para resposta, ali no: $to_reposta="admin@nomedosite.com.br";

Mas se eu altero, da o seguinte erro:

> SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 553 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user admin@nomedosite.com.br SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: nomedoemail@gmail.com

Comment: Que tipo de erro?

Comment: SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 553 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user admin@nomedosite.com.br
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: nomedoemail@gmail.com

Tem que ser um outro e-mail da hospedagem?

Comment: E se no `login_usermail` e `senha_usermail` você colocar as credenciais do e-mail que está tentando enviar?

Comment: Ai da o erro: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Pois tem que ser um e-mail do domínio!

Comment: Aparentemente essa é uma restrição de segurança do seu servidor SMTP, não aceitar um endereço "reply-to" de domínio diferente do de envio.

Comment: Existe alguma forma de habilitar isso? É uma hospedagem da UOL!

Comment: Já tentou usar `$mail->AddReplyTo` ao invés de tentar informar um outro e-mail como `from`?

Comment: retirando o: $mail->From = "$to_reposta";   ?????

E colocando o: $mail->AddReplyTo

?

Comment: @user3081, não. O método `from` continua sendo necessário. Adicione uma outra linha com essa instrução. Verifique a minha resposta na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é usar o método `addReplyTo` da classe `PHPMailer`.

Implementação:

```
$mail->AddReplyTo = "$to_resposta";
```

[Link da Documentação.](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addReplyTo)